# Hilbert space theory

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume ${\mathcal{H}}$ is a real Hilbert space and $T:{\mathcal{H}}\to{\mathcal{H}}$ is a linear, bounded operator. Let $T^{*}$ be the adjoint operator, i.e. $(Tf,g)=(f,T^{*}g)$ for all $f,g\in{\mathcal{H}}$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the the inner product in ${\mathcal{H}}$. Assume $T\,T^{*}=I$ where $I$ denotes the identity map. Is $T^{*}=T^{-1}$?

Comment: Hint: The right and left shifts on $\ell^{2}$ are adjoints of each other.

Comment: If $T$ is a right shift and $T^{*}$ is a left shift, why is $T\,T^{*}=I$?

Comment: $T^\ast T$ is the identity, $TT^\ast$ is not.

Comment: @guest61 Only $T^*T$ is the identity because you are essentially undoing what you first did. More specifically, $T^*T(c_0,c_1,c_2,...) = T^* (0,c_0,c_1,c_2,...) = (c_0,c_1,c_2,...)$. On the other hand, if we consider $TT^*$ we get that $TT^*(c_0,c_1,c_2,...) = T(c_1,c_2,c_3,...) = (0,c_1,c_2,c_3,...)$.